# List to dictionary - improvement?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The following code does what I want, but any other way more python-style of doing it?

Having file in the format:

```
key1:value1,key2:value2,...
key21:value21,key22:value22,...
.
EOF
```

and code:

```
file = open(fileName, 'r')
for lines in file:
    line = lines.split(",")
    my_dict = {}
    for item in line:
        key_value = item.split(":")
        my_dict.update({key_value[0]:key_value[1]})
```

Thanks

Comment: frankly, what you have looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `split()`:

list.txt:

```
key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3
key21:value21,key22:value22
```

**Hence**:

```
with open("list.txt") as fileObj:
    content = fileObj.readlines()
    # you may also want to remove empty lines
    content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]

    for line in content:
        for elem in line.split(","):
            print({elem .split(":")[0] : elem.split(":")[1]})
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'key1': 'value1'}
{'key2': 'value2'}
{'key3': 'value3'}
{'key21': 'value21'}
{'key22': 'value22'}
```

**OR**

If you want them stored in the dict:

```
for line in content:
    for x in line.split(","):
        dict_.update({x.split(":")[0] : x.split(":")[1]})

print(dict_['key1'])    # value1
```

Answer (score 4):

A faster & more pythonic way would be to use `csv` module (comma separated by default) and split items in a double flattened generator comprehension fed to  `dict` that accepts tuples with 2 elements:

```
import csv
with open("test.csv",newline="") as f:  # replace ,newline="" by ,"rb" in python 2
    cr = csv.reader(f)
    d = dict(x.split(":") for row in cr for x in row)

print(d)
```

result:

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key22': 'value22', 'key21': 'value21', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

non-csv version:

```
import csv
with open("test.csv") as f:
    d = dict(x.split(":") for line in f for x in line.split(","))
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the `csv` module for this. Splitting on commas is honestly easier than parsing csv correctly - when parsing csv the file should be opened with `newline=""` in python 3, and in `rb` mode in python2. (You did neither :P)

Comment: I never had any issue when reading a csv file. I'll provide a non-csv solution

Comment: It's true that it's rarely a problem, but the docs say it should be done, so.... ([py3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader), [py2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#csv.reader))